# string literal contains an unescaped line break problem of carriage return with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem of carriage return in a textarea \r\n
All is working fine but when I write a carriage return
I have a error message string literal contains an unescaped line break
My code :

```js
e.preventDefault();
    
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var aInputFeedback=document.getElementsByClassName('inputfeedback');
    for(var i=0;i<aInputFeedback.length;i++){
    if(i==2){
    value = aInputFeedback[i].value.replace( /\r/g, '\\r' );
    aInputFeedback[i].value=value;
    
    
    }
    //alert(aInputFeedback[i].value);
    eval("var inputValue"+i+"=\""+aInputFeedback[i].value+"\";");
    //ICI REPLACE 
                     
    alert(aInputFeedback[i].value);
    
    }
```

My regex doesn't work
Thanks for your help

Comment: Your snippet is not runnable... On which line are you getting the error? The `eval` line? (that use of eval with the content of a textarea is a massive security problem. I could use it to execute arbitrary code in your page)

Comment: try using `\n` instead of `\r`

Comment: Removing the line-breaks from the input value doesn't work, because the error is due to messy quoting. Just remove the eval, and fix the quoting in the expression creating the value to assign to an _array_  you should use instead of "indexed variables".

Comment: thanks I agree how to create dynamical variable without eval?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [spec](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#normalize-newlines) addresses the line break issue with a process it names *normailizing newlines* and states this:

> To normalize newlines in a string, replace every U+000D CR U+000A LF
> code point pair with a single U+000A LF code point, and then replace
> every remaining U+000D CR code point with a U+000A LF code point.

So as brunoff suggests, change: `\r` to `\n` in the RegEx pattern.

Comment: It doesn't work with \n but the error message comes from the eval and the " and \" of the eval
how to replace the eval , ?
Thanks

Comment: The RegEx does work and this does answer you question. The issue with the `eval` is a different question. But, I don't understand why you don't just do: `window['inputValue'+i] = a[i].value;` rather than `eval` anyway.

Comment: I replace the eval with a simple array 
The problem came from the double quote of the eval and \r\n created a space in my string 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer as it did solve the question you posed: "_My regex doesn't work_"